# объединение таблиц со сложением значений MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, таблицы

Есть 2 таблицы forwards и goals 
Делаю запрос, чтоб объединить их в одну

```
SELECT
    f_name AS Игрок, num AS count
FROM 
    forwards inner JOIN goals
ON forwards.id = goals.forward;
```

Получается так [image: пикча2]

Мне нужно чтобы при объединении данных в таблице goals получилась сумма забитых голов и без дублирования имени... Не могу разобраться - хелп
 [image: пикча]

forward = id человека в таблице forwards.

Comment: Группировка GROUP BY, суммирование SUM().

Comment: @Akina , делаю запрос `SELECT forwards.f_name AS Игрок, SUM(goals.num) AS COUNT GROUP BY f_name.forwards` - выдает ошибку unknown table 'forwards' in field list, не понимаю(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете использовать следующий запрос:

```
SELECT
    f_name AS Игрок, SUM(num) AS count
FROM 
    forwards 
INNER JOIN goals ON forwards.id = goals.forward
GROUP BY forwards.id, forwards.f_name;
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, можете мне пояснить почему в select мы берем **f_name**  и **num** из разных таблиц, но пишем FROM Forwards из одной? Как работает эта цепочка? Буду очень признателен

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/256045/

Comment: https://schoolsw3.com/sql/sql_join_inner.php